# .NET Dependency Injection Auto-Registration vs Performance

Tags: .net, performance, design-patterns, dependency-injection, startup

My company uses Unity container with **Code As Configuration** in desktop application. After reading book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://manning.com/seemann/) I thought to propose **Auto-Registration** using **Convention over Configuration** as the book says use **Composition Root** to compose the application’s object graph and you should prefer Auto-Registration (to avoid violating DRY and to get more manageable code).

But I also watched pluralsight course [Building High-Performance Windows 8 Applications](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-high-performance-windows8-applications) and author said:

> assembly load is expensive process as far as performance concern and it is important to avoid unnecessary loading of an assembly in startup path.

I am worried about performance using Auto-Registration in startup as it requires to use reflection and loading of all assemblies.

I like to understand what is the best approach. Has anyone faced performance issue and dropped Auto-Registration or found intermediate option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a **DI Container** like Unity, you have basically [two options](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) of registering your dependencies:

- Convention over Configuration using **Auto-Registration**
- Explicitly register

With **Auto-Registration** you typically apply **Assembly Scanning** and reflect over the types in a given set of assemblies. This **Batch-Registers** all those types in the Container.

With Explicitly register on the other hand, you list all types one-by-one in code (or XML, or any other form).

Both options however will cause all assemblies that contain the types to register, to be loaded at application start-up.

This is something that is typically hard to prevent when using a DI Container, since the DI Container needs those mappings before-hand. The typical use is to configure the container during start-up, and after that only resolve from it.

With [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) on the other hand, it is much easier to delay loading of assemblies until those types are used for the first time.

Say for instance you're building a MVC web application with Pure DI, it might look a bit like this:

```
public static Controller CreateController(Type type)
{
    var dbContext = new CommerceContext(this.connectionString);

    if (type == typeof(HomeController))
        return 
            new HomeController(
                new ProductRepository(
                    dbContext));

    if (type == typeof(LogoutController))
        return
            new LogoutController(
                new UserRepository(
                    dbContext));

    else
        return base.CreateController(type);
}
```

Now let's say that `ProductRepository` and `UserRepository` each live in different assemblies. Now when the `CreateController` method is called for the first time, which will be very shortly after start-up, this method will be JITted. When a method gets JITted, all assemblies of all referenced types will be loaded. In this case that would mean that both the assembly of `ProductRepository` and that of `UserRepository` would both be loaded.

Since `HomeController` is very likely created very soon after the application starts, it wouldn't make much sense to try to delay the loading of the `ProductRepository` assembly, but it might make sense for `UserRepository`, since the `LogoutController` might be created much later in the application's lifetime.

We can prevent `UserRepository` assembly to be loaded, by extracting it to its own method:

```
public static Controller CreateController(Type type)
{
    ...
    if (type == typeof(LogoutController))
        return
            new LogoutController(
                CreateUserRepository(dbContext));
    ...
}

// Extracted to method to enable lazy assembly loading
private IUserRepository CreateUserRepository(CommerceContext context) 
{
    return new UserRepository(dbContext));
}
```

By delegating the creation of the `UserRepository` class to the `CreateUserRepository` method, we can prevent its assembly from being loaded too early. This obviously only works when no other types from that assembly are needed earlier. If, for instance, the `IUserRepository` interface is defined in the same assembly, this means the assembly will still be loaded when `CreateController` gets JITted, since `CreateController` depends on `IUserRepository`.

This example however is a bit contrived, since for a web application it usually makes little sense to do this kind of lazy loading of assemblies, since there are other techniques to prevent the user from noticing the application start-up time.

This brings me to the following, although it might be important to delay loading of applications in your **Desktop application**, you really need to **measure this** first. In many applications this **will absolutely not be a problem**. I worked myself on several desktop applications that all used DI and a DI Container and did pre-loading of all assemblies at start up, in the performance wasn't a problem in most cases.

In the other (single) case where this actually a problem was, we solved this by showing a fancy splash screen to show the user the application was being loaded.

That said, even when using a DI container, there are ways to delay loading assemblies, but this is a rather sophisticated practice, which I would not pursuit unless, there is an actual performance penalty and can't be solved in any other way.

Comment: Thanks Steaven for explanation. I should measure performance before worrying about it.